# VBA Determine Date Of Nth Specific Day Of Month

Tags: excel, vba, date

Good Afternoon,

I would like help with VBA code that will return the nth business date of a month while considering US Federal Holidays.  For instance, if I wanted to return the date for the 18th business day of January, 2014 the value should be 01/28/2014.  There are two federal holidays in January which make the date be the 28th as opposed to the 24th.

The only code I was able to find was:

```
finaldate = Application.Evaluate("workday(Date(2014,01,0),18)")
```

This will find the 18th business day but does not take the holidays into consideration.

I do have code built that will return the dates for all the federal holidays within VBA.  These values update automatically based on the current year.  I would prefer not to have to reference any table on the workbook.

```
'Holiday Check

NewYearsDay = "01/01/" & EndYear ' New Year's Day, January 1st.
MLKJrDay = NDow(EndYear, 1, 3, 2) ' Birthday of Martin Luther King, third Monday in January.
PresidentsDay = NDow(EndYear, 2, 3, 2) ' Washington's Birthday, third Monday in February since 1971; prior to that year, it was celebrated on the traditional date of February 22.
MayMondayCount = DOWsInMonth(EndYear, 5, 2) ' Count number of Mondays in the month of May.  Used to determine Memorial Day Date.
MemorialDay = NDow(EndYear, 5, MayMondayCount, 2) ' Memorial Day, last Monday in May since 1971; from 1868 to 1970 it was celebrated on May 30, and was called Decoration Day for part of that time.
IndepDay = "07/04/" & EndYear ' United States of America's Independence Day, July 4.
LaborDay = NDow(EndYear, 9, 1, 2) ' Labor Day, first Monday in September.
ColumbDay = NDow(EndYear, 10, 2, 2) ' Columbus Day, second Monday in October (federal holiday since 1971).
VeterDay = "11/11/" & EndYear ' Veterans Day, November 11th (except from 1971 to 1977, inclusive, when it was celebrated on the fourth Monday in October; formerly known as Armistice).
ThanksgDay = NDow(EndYear, 11, 4, 5) ' Thanksgiving Day, fourth Thursday in November.
ChristDay = "12/25/" & EndYear ' Christmas Day, December 25th.
```

Any help showing how to build the code in VBA that accomplishes this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: is it what you want: [WORKDAY](http://www.google.ru/url?q=http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/workday-HP005209339.aspx&sa=U&ei=v65aU7X1NsmD4gTG0oFY&ved=0CB0QFjAA&sig2=Z5YtSj9mMeL6wBn1Eg2nrA&usg=AFQjCNGV_4miSfvaxTFI3Rsx6mYL2j8DqA) or [WORKDAY.INTL](http://www.google.ru/url?q=http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/workday-intl-function-HA010354380.aspx&sa=U&ei=x65aU4oN7PDiBNLrgcAB&ved=0CB0QFjAA&sig2=sABQrkgbXLw7_CvCpY54qg&usg=AFQjCNGn5S0dVPnl-DK658Lyu3pfW6YHtg)?

Comment: @simoco I believe that WORKDAY.INTL may work.  It looks like I need an array built for the holidays. My experience with arrays is very limited.  Would you mind showing how to build my holiday's into an array and then apply it to the WORKDAY.INTL code?

Comment: 1) you can create array directly in formula: `=WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(2006,1,1),20,"0000011",{"2006/1/2","2006/1/16"})` or 2) you can put all your holidays somewhere in the sheet, e.g. in range `A1:A10` and then: `=WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(2006,1,1),20,"0000011",A1:A10)`

Comment: also read this: http://www.google.ru/url?q=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128803(v%3Doffice.14).aspx&sa=U&ei=GbJaU9aODIrw4gSYq4Bg&ved=0CCsQFjAC&sig2=Nsz-36KRK9PwPYayQNPbng&usg=AFQjCNGWszvwIYTPenkMKIsV4HVQuAFiAg

Comment: @simoco Thank you.  So your info and the web link seem to provide the exact information I need.  The only problem is I can't get it to work.  I receive error 438 "Object doesn't support this property of method" when I literally cut and pasted the exact code from the web site.  The code is:  holidays = Array(#11/24/2011#, #12/25/2011#)
newDate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(#11/20/2011#, 10, "1000111", holidays)

Comment: what is your excel version? `WorkDay_Intl` works for excel 2010+. For excel 2003,2007 use `WorkDay`

Comment: @simoco  I have 2007.  How can I restructure this code so that I don't receive a compile error.  newDate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(date(2014,1,0), 1, holidays)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51460/discussion-between-john-w-and-simoco)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, credit for this answer should go to **Simoco**.  It was his comments above that solved my problem.  I wanted to mark this question answered and this was the only way I knew how.

The short answer is Workday was the way to go for Excel 2007.  If you are using Excel 2010, `Workday` or `Workday_Intl` will also work.  Both opitions allow the user to enter holidays that should be excluded.  I used `Dateserial` for my date and built an array using the holiday dates I had calculated earlier.

```
Sub Test_toFind_Business_Day()

Dim StartMonth As Long, StartYear As Long, StartDay As Long, DayCount As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim finaldate As Date, newDate As Date, DateHolder As Date
Dim holidays As Variant
Dim EndYear As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice_Criteria")

StartDate = ws.Range("PreviousSettlement").Value
EndDate = DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate)
EndYear = DatePart("yyyy", EndDate)

DayCount = ws.Range("SettlementDay").Value
StartMonth = Month(EndDate)
StartYear = Year(EndDate)

holidays = Array(NewYearsDay, MLKJrDay, PresidentsDay, MemorialDay, IndepDay, LaborDay, ColumbDay, _
                VeterDay, ThanksgDay, ChristDay)

DateHolder = DateSerial(StartYear, StartMonth, 1)

newDate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(DateHolder, DayCount, holidays)

End Sub
```

I hope this helps anyone else having difficulty incorporating workday function into their VBA.